# Laravel errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

was following a few different tutorials trying to learn foreign key migration. I have Laravel v9.

Can't solve this error:

```
General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`galleries` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `galleries` add constraint `galleries_album_id_foreign` foreign key (`album_id`) references `albums` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Migration file:

```
Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('album_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->longText('details');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums')
    ->onDelete('cascade');;
});
```

```
Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string("name");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'd appreciate the help as I have no idea what to do.

I tried: `$table->integer('album_id')->unsigned();` which didn't work.
Made sure there's no typo. Everything looks good to me as I was following the tutorial on this.

Comment: Maybe try just `bigInteger()` instead of `unsignedBigInteger()`, or `$table->foreignId('album_id')->constrained();`. Usually that error means that the datatypes of the two columns are not the same. Or, make sure your `albums` migration is running before your `galleries` migration. I think you get a similar error if the referenced table doesn't exist.

Comment: You cannot reference a table before it is created. Alter the timestamp in the filename of the migration so that the albums table is created first

Comment: Thanks guys.
Nothing worked. I tried:
1- bigInteger() instead of unsignedBigInteger() as Tim suggested. 
2- added constrained(), which had no effect.
3- Edited the filename to change the timestamps, still the issue persists.

Comment: I do see the albums table created. But the migrate breaks as soon as it reaches `$table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums')`

Answer (score 1):

```
        $table->bigInteger("album_id")->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('album_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('albums')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31397050)

Comment: @RahulBaradia Please pay attention when reviewing. This is not a link-only answer. Although code-only answers are generally frowned upon and deemed downvote-worthy, they are still an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was, I had to change the name of my database schema as to:

```
Schema::create('galleriesx', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

Works now. Have no idea why this happened. Would like some insight if you can help, thanks.